# how to build a delayed / buffered pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Is it possible to build a buffered pipe  that retains data (for some given amount of bytes or some given time) from standard linux tools like cat, dd etc.?

For example to collect a defined amount of packets, audio data or something else.

Eg. to build a script `delaybuffer` to do something like that:

```
arecord | delaybuffer 16000 | aplay
```

to playback the recorded audio 16000 bytes delayed.

Comment: Which bytes should be read for 16000 bytes? Zero bytes? Something else? How would the delaybuffer command know how many bytes aplay consumes per read?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the buffer program shouldn't write till it **reads 16000 bytes**? Once it reads stipulated bytes, start writing all the data?

Comment: Be careful with this -- if you choose a size that's too large the pipe may become full, causing `arecord`'s writes to block and your whole chain to stall.  According to `man 7 pipe` recent Linux kernels have pipe capacity of 65535. So, 16000 is safe, but beware that making this too large will break it.

Comment: Does a C compiler count as a 'standard linux tool'?

Comment: I would not expect the kernel pipe buffer to hold my data, but some `delaybuffer`'s own memory. The answer below seem to match this.

Comment: The C compiler would be a standard tool, but downloading a source file and build it on every system I occassionally run into the need for this tool would be not.

Comment: Well on the other hand, the answer below would need the install of a package which isn't 'standard' either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool called `buffer` which does the job. ([Link to the Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/en/squeeze/buffer) - might be also available in other distributions.).

> Buffer uses shared memory to convert a variable input data rate to a constant output data rate.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I thought of. Just wondered if there is any possibility to get a disk based buffer? Thus it could be used to buffer large delays of video data too for example...

Comment: I think this is the answer, even if it usually needs the install of a tool on most systems. However there seems no simple solution without.

Comment: If you need to ensure the buffer is full before writing, there is a `-p` option that you need to use. There is also another tool called `mbuffer` that works similarly.

Answer (score 6):

Another way of doing it is with dd (if buffer does not exist on your dist).

```
    arecord | dd ibs=16000 iflag=fullblock oflag=dsync | aplay
```

I am not really sure about the flags, there might be better ways than just burst a block at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The following gives a 4 second time handicap to `cdparanoia` to extract track 7 of a audio CD before starting reading the output.
Works well as a command line cd-player.

```
cdparanoia 7 ~/temp.wav & sleep 4 ; tail -f -c +1 ~/temp.wav | aplay
```